# Why is it a bad idea to tell your server to parse HTML as PHP?

Tags: php, html, security, parsing, .htaccess

You know you can make a server parse HTML pages as PHP (execute PHP code in a HTML doc) using .htaccess?

Well, some people say it's bad to do so. Why?

Some people also say it opens a security vulnerability in your application. How?

The source code is still removed before the document reaches the browser, so it can't be the case of unauthorized access to source code, right?

Comment: all mine do, its not  a bad idea, if you know what you are doing

Comment: When people make baseless comments like that I usually ask for a source or reference.  There is also this rumour going around that PHP is insecure because it is ... php.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me start with a little story: back when I was a security contact at a Linux distribution vendor, the PHP security team begged Linux vendors to stop calling interpreter crashes *security bugs*, even when the PHP interpreter was running *inside* the web server (say, `mod_php` on Apache). (At the time, roughly one interpreter crash was being found per week.)

It took a little bit of conversation for them to actually convince us that whoever supplied the running PHP code is completely trusted and any attempt to control what the scripts *could* do from the interpreter was misguided -- and if someone figured out how to crash the interpreter to walk around the restrictions it tried to impose (such as the [entire silly safe mode pile of crap](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)), it was *not* a security flaw, because the safe execution of scripts was *not* the goal of the PHP interpreter -- it never was and never would be.

I'm actually pretty happy with the end result of the discussions -- it clearly defined PHP's security goals: You should only ever allow execution of PHP code that you 100% completely trust. If you do not trust it, you do not run it. It's that simple.

Whatever operating system resources are available to the interpreter are *all* available and fair game, regardless of whether the script exploits a bug in the interpreter or just does something unexpected.

So, please do not allow random code to be executed in the context of your webserver unless that is what you *really* want.

Please use the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) to guide what resources are available to every program.

Consider using a [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tool such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/) to further confine what your programs can and can't do. I've worked on the AppArmor project since 2001 or so and am fairly confident that with a day's effort most system administrators can enhance their sites security in a meaningful way with AppArmor. Please evaluate several options, as the different tools are designed around different security models -- one or another may be a better fit.

But whatever you do, please don't run your server in a fashion that needlessly opens it up to attack via extra vectors.

Answer (score 8):

The main concern is if you ever move your code to another server or let someone else work with your code, server settings, or `.htaccess` file your html pages could stop being parsed by the PHP interpreter.

In that case the PHP code would be served up to the browser.

Answer (score 3):

There's a security vulnerability in that that if you do that, HTML files are really PHP files, and so uploading them should be taken as seriously as uploading PHP files.  Often people don't see uploading HTML files as as big a deal, precisely because they don't expect them to be set to parse as PHP (so others in your company might inadvertently open up a security hole). [PaulP.R.O.'s answer notes that a security problem can also arise in the opposite direction - due to PHP being mistaken for HTML later on when this setting is mistakenly dropped.]

There's also a bit of a performance issue, in that every HTML file then has to be run through the PHP parser (even if it happens to contain no PHP).

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML as PHP is bad(ish) for speed and organization reasons.

- HTML files parsed as PHP will technically load slower, because you're invoking the PHP engine.
- But mostly it's bad for organizational purposes: As your project expands, imagine hunting for embedded PHP code in HTML files.  When browsing your project, your file extension should be the true indicator of that files purpose.  If a form submits to 'login.php' you can be reasonably sure it contains server code.  But 'login.html' could just be another HTML page.

Concerning the rest of your comment, I'm not sure about the security aspect, but I'm thinking mixing up your HTML and PHP output could lead to unnoticed XSS vulnerabilities?  Not the expert when it comes to that though.

Comment: XSS is about JavaScript.  If an attacker is running PHP code on your server, you have a more serious problem.

Comment: Thanks!

I wonder, if you mix inline Ajax into your HTML file parsed as PHP, with a form submitting to itself ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), can that open you up to XSS attacks?

Comment: Only if you put the submitted form data into the HTML response (or any future HTML response) without sanitizing it first, which is the real mistake.  Having an HTML file parsed as PHP is no different from having a PHP file, except that it's less clear to other people what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad for speed, and if the PHP interpreter doesn't work for some reason, the PHP code will show up in the page source. If you have, for instance, a database username and password in the PHP code, anyone could connect and access your database easily.

And as zed said, it is bad for organisational reasons. Instead of updating one file, you would need to update all of the files on your site to make a simple change.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing the server to parse HTML files as PHP shows that you are using no propery application design patterns. That is to say that you are blazing your own path instead of doing things the recommended way. There is a reason that designs like MVC (which separate of concerns), exist.

One problem with allowing arbitrary documents to be directly called is the loss of a "front controller" (usually an index.php) which helps to tighten down the number of doorways into your application.

You can have many paths into your application, but you have that many more possible attack routes you must cover in your designs.

Comment: Which isn't a bad thing, necessarily.  You don't become a leader in the industry by doing things that others have already found the best way to do.

Comment: This is a good analyse. MVC or not, a controller is your main(), great stuff.